# Python / Django - edit render output

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm new to python and I have the following issue.
I have a Counterpart database with two boolean fields that are "is_client" and "is_supplier". When a counterpart is added could be either client or supplier or both.

I want to display that if is_client=True c_type = "client", if is_supplier=True c_type = "supplier" and if both are True c_type = "client / supplier"

How can I do it in the following function?

```
class CounterpartsListView(ListView):
model = Counterpart
template_name = "counterparts/view_list.html" 
context_object_name = "counterparts"

def get_queryset(self):
    c_type = self.kwargs.get("type")
    if c_type == "suppliers":
        if Counterpart.objects.filter(is_supplier=True).count() >= 1:
            return (
                Counterpart.objects.filter(is_supplier=True)
                .order_by("counterpart_name")
                .extra(select={"Supplier": "is_supplier"})
            )
        else:
            return Counterpart.objects.all().order_by("counterpart_name")
    elif c_type == "customers":
        if Counterpart.objects.filter(is_client=True).count() >= 1:
            return (
                Counterpart.objects.filter(is_client=True)
                .order_by("counterpart_name")
                .extra(select={"Customer": "is_client"})
            )
        else:
            return Counterpart.objects.all().order_by("counterpart_name")
    else:
        return Counterpart.objects.all().order_by("counterpart_name")
```

this is the html output, how can I add the c_type attribute ?

```
{% for counterpart in counterparts %}
     <tr>
        <td>{{ counterpart.counterpart_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ counterpart.city }}</td>
        <td>{{ counterpart.country }}</td>
        <td>{{ counterpart.c_type }}</td>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, I was thinking to change the input method and instead of two separate fields (is_client and is_supplier), have just one called c_type and add an the value (customer or supplier) and in case is both add an array. Or what would it be a better solution?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out.. at least this is a solution that worked for my case.. it was so obvious that I could not see it :)
**view_all.html**

```
{% if counterpart.is_supplier %} Supplier {% endif %}
{% if counterpart.is_supplier and counterpart.is_client %} / {% endif %}
{% if counterpart.is_client %} Customer {% endif %}
```

I'm still interested to learn other ways that I could better handle it
Thanks